# AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work in SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql, database, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE detectives(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    certification_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT detectives_pk PRIMARY KEY (id
);
```

It says: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.

Any help with this?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the manual on how to create incrementing columns and not use mysql code which wil not work in SQl server. Hint look at identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing closing `)` and using incorrect syntax for an `IDENTITY` field.

```
CREATE TABLE detectives(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    certification_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT detectives_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

To

```
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
```

Answer (score 0):

you've to make the column identity if you want auto increment. your code will be

```
CREATE TABLE detectives(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    certification_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT detectives_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```